# In Javascript fetch() Why are there two promises resolved before we get our actual data?

Tags: javascript

In the following example why is there another promise chained after first is resolved? We had the response object from fetch even when the first promise was resolved .

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(myBlob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
});
```

why not just say

```
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(response.blob());
      myImage.src = objectURL;
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob: _“The blob() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a Blob.”_ - so the first way is the _correct_ way to do this, whereas your second one probably rather works due to _luck_, since you are not “waiting” for the blob to actually be created - so that _might_ work under specific circumstances, but it might as well fail in others.

Comment: as @CBroe says, when you use a thenable in your response you can return it to ensure it is fulffilled when the then is called. Also I sometimes find it elegant to chain thens to separate in different functions specific operations. Here the first would be blobbing the stream, and the second would be to apply the result to the image

Answer (score 2):

What we request from FETCH API comes back to us hidden in body as a **readable stream**. We need to call an appropriate method to convert this readable stream into data we can consume. Therefore two promises.

We need to call an appropriate method to convert this readable stream into data we can consume. Some of them are-

- `Response.clone()` - Creates a clone of a Response object.
- `Response.error()` - Returns a new Response object associated with a network error.
- `Response.redirect()` - Creates a new response with a different URL.

Response implements `Body`, so it also has the following methods available to it:

- `Body.arrayBuffer()` - Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with an ArrayBuffer.
- `Body.blob()` - Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a Blob.
- `Body.formData()` - Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a FormData object.
- `Body.json()` - Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.
- `Body.text()` - Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with a USVString (text).

In your case, it's Blob.