# Javascript Promises: Multiple .then(..) clauses versus one .then(..) clause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

The context is this: I have a 'toy' node.js server that returns the following json:
{ "message" : "hello there" }
And this is returned if you do a GET request to "http://localhost:3060/"
So, very simple.

Here is my 'baseline' code, featuring multiple .then(..) clauses

```
  3 function footgun() {
  4     fetch('http://localhost:3060/')
  5             .then(res => res.json())
  6             .then(json => json.message)
  7             .then(msg => console.log(msg));
```

The output is:
**hello there**

Excellent.  Very good.  That's what I wanted.

I have been reading about how promises are implemented.
And so I know that each .then() returns a Promise object. But isn't that wasteful ?
Surely it would be more efficient to pack everything into one .then() clause ?
Like this:

```
  3 function footgun() {
  4     fetch('http://localhost:3060/')
  5             .then(res => {
  6                 const json = res.json();
  7                 const msg = json.message;
  8                 console.log(msg);
  9             });
```

The output is:
**undefined**

That's the problem.  Why is the result 'undefined' ?
Why does this not work inside a single .then(..) clause ?

Thanks to anyone that volunteers an explanation or suggestion. :-)
Gene Keto

Comment: or [In Javascript fetch() Why are there two promises resolved before we get our actual data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45938562/in-javascript-fetch-why-are-there-two-promises-resolved-before-we-get-our-actu)

Comment: or [Why does .json() return a promise, but not when it passes through .then()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555031/why-does-json-return-a-promise-but-not-when-it-passes-through-then)

Comment: or even closer to your question [Can I somehow get the fetch response in the first `then`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084274/can-i-somehow-get-the-fetch-response-in-the-first-then)

Comment: I didn't read this question as only about why do you need a `.then()` on `res.json()`.   It's also about when to use `.then()` and when not to as the OP shows something like this too `.then(json => json.message)` which is superfluous so this questions is about MORE than just what those other links are discussing.  See the answer below for a complete answer that covers all the issues in the OP's post, not just some of them.  No need to dup a question that isn't fully answered by the dups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use an additional `.then()` when you have another asynchronous operation that you need the result of.

So, in this:

```
  3 function footgun() {
  4     fetch('http://localhost:3060/')
  5             .then(res => res.json())
  6             .then(json => json.message)
  7             .then(msg => console.log(msg));
```

You need a `.then()` for `fetch()` and you need one for `res.json()` as both are asynchronous and both return a promise.

You do NOT need this one:

```
.then(json => json.message)
```

as it just wastes a few cycles that you don't need to do.  In the sequence you've shown, this would be the most efficient:

```
  3 function footgun() {
  4     fetch('http://localhost:3060/')
  5             .then(res => res.json())
  6             .then(data => console.log(data.message));
```

You use a `.then()` ONLY for each asynchronous operation that returns a promise.

---

Of course, it's even simpler if you use await:

```
  3 async function footgun() {
  4     let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3060/');
  5     let data = await res.json();
  6     console.log(data.message);
```

Similarly, you only use `await` when you have an asynchronous operation that returns a promise.

---

In your second example that doesn't work:

```
  3 function footgun() {
  4     fetch('http://localhost:3060/')
  5             .then(res => {
  6                 const json = res.json();
  7                 const msg = json.message;
  8                 console.log(msg);
  9             });
```

`res.json();` is an asynchronous operation that returns a promise that you never wait to resolve.  So, `json` ends up being a promise (not your desired data).  So, when you try to reference `json.message` it's `undefined` because `json` here is a promise and a promise doesn't have a `.message` property (thus you get `undefined`).